# Why does the output of my Python program look this (very odd) way?

Tags: python, multithreading, output

I've worked with Python for a while, but I've never really done any concurrency in it before today. I stumbled upon [this blog post](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/01/python-concurrency-an-example-of-a-queue/) and decided to make a similar (but simpler) example:

```
import os
import threading
import Queue

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.num = num

    def run(self):
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            #print "{} :: {}".format(self.num, text)
            print "%s :: %s" % (self.num, text)
            self.queue.task_done()

nonsense = ["BLUBTOR", "more nonsense", "cookies taste good", "what is?!"]
queue = Queue.Queue()

for i in xrange(4):
    # Give the worker the queue and also its "number"
    t = Worker(queue, i)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

for gibberish in nonsense:
    queue.put(gibberish)

queue.join()
```

It seems to work fine, but there seems to be some problem with the prints which I cannot figure out. A couple of test runs:

```
chris@DPC3:~/code/pythonthreading$ python owntest.py 
0 :: BLUBTOR
 1 :: more nonsense
3 :: cookies taste good
 2 :: what is?!
chris@DPC3:~/code/pythonthreading$ python owntest.py 
0 :: BLUBTOR
2 :: more nonsense
3 :: cookies taste good0 :: what is?!

chris@DPC3:~/code/pythonthreading$ python owntest.py 
2 :: BLUBTOR
 3 :: more nonsense1 :: cookies taste good

 2 :: what is?!
chris@DPC3:~/code/pythonthreading$
```

Why is the output formatted this oddly?

Comment: You can use `sys.stdout.write(message)` instead :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` is not atomic.

The following line:

```
        print "%s :: %s" % (self.num, text)
```

get translated into the following bytecodes:

```
         24 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%s :: %s')
         27 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
         30 LOAD_ATTR                3 (num)
         33 LOAD_FAST                1 (text)
         36 BUILD_TUPLE              2
         39 BINARY_MODULO       
         40 PRINT_ITEM          
         41 PRINT_NEWLINE
```

As you can see, there are two printing bytecodes there (`PRINT_ITEM` and `PRINT_NEWLINE`). If the thread gets preempted between the two, you would see what you are seeing.

I agree with others that `sys.stdout.write()` is a safer bet for this use case since:

1. it forces you to format the entire string before you write it (with `print` you can accidentally use `print a, b, c,` and end up with three separate writes instead of one);
2. it sidesteps the issues of softspace and automatic newline, both of which can interact with `print` statements in other parts of the program.

Comment: This is very helpful information. Making the newline manually fixes the problem: `print "{} :: {}\n".format(self.num, text),`

Answer (score 6):

Printing is not threadsafe.

While some characters are being copied to the `stdout` stream by one thread, another thread is scheduled that is *also* printing and it gets to copy characters to `stdout` stream.

The result is that your `stdout` doesn't contain discreet results of `print` calls but mixed outputs from different threads, all jumbled together.

The work-around is to use `sys.stdout.write()` instead; that *is* an atomic (threadsafe) operation. Make sure you include an explicit `\n` newline.